# java web server program

Tags: java, sockets

The goal is to develop a web server that when accessed via a web browser will return the HTTP request message that it receives.

I run the program from a virtual machine environment and access the server from my local machine.  The code I have is below.  When I type in my IP address while the server is running, I just get a Null Pointer Exception.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class proj1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int port = 9000;

        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);

        while(true) {
            Socket connection = socket.accept();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(connection);
            Thread thread = new Thread(request);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

}

final class HttpRequest implements Runnable {
    //Declare Variables
    final static String CRLF = "\r\n";
    Socket socket;

    //Constructor
    public HttpRequest(Socket socket) throws Exception {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    //Unimplemented Runnable Method
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            processRequest();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private void processRequest() throws Exception {
        //Reference Socket Input and Output Streams
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        DataOutputStream os = null;

        //Input Stream Filters
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(null);

        //Request Line of HTTP Request Message
        String requestLine = br.readLine();

        //Extract FileName From Request Line
        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(requestLine);
        tokens.nextToken();
        String fileName = tokens.nextToken();

        fileName = "." + fileName;

        //Open Requested File
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        boolean fileExists = true;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            fileExists = false;
        }

        //Debug
        System.out.println(requestLine);
        String headerLine = null;
        while ((headerLine = br.readLine()).length() != 0) {
            System.out.println(headerLine);
        }

        //Construct Response Message
        String statusLine = null;
        String contentTypeLine = null;
        String entityBody = null;

        if (fileExists) {
            statusLine = "statusLine";
            contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: " + contentType(fileName) + CRLF;
        } else {
            statusLine = "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found" + CRLF;
            contentTypeLine = "Content-Type: text/html" + CRLF;
            entityBody = "<HTML>" + "<HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE></HEAD>" + "<BODY>Not Found</BODY></HTML>";
        }

        //Send Lines
        os.writeBytes(statusLine);
        os.writeBytes(contentTypeLine);
        os.writeBytes(CRLF);

        //Send Entity Body
        if (fileExists) {
            sendBytes(fis, os);
            fis.close();
        } else {
            os.writeBytes(entityBody);
        }

        //Close Streams and Sockets
        os.close();
        br.close();
        socket.close();
    }

    private static void sendBytes(FileInputStream fis, OutputStream os) throws Exception {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;

        while ((bytes = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
    }

    private static String contentType(String fileName) {
        if (fileName.endsWith(".htm") || fileName.endsWith(".html")) {
            return "text/html";
        }

        return "application/octet-stream";
    }

}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at proj1.main(proj1.java:10)
```

That is the error code when I try to run the program in eclipse...  When I run the code in my virtual machine, it runs fine but whenever I access the IP address of the server on my machine, I get no response message and a Null Pointer Exception on the virtual machine.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of your exception.

Comment: If you could just place the code where the exception occurs that would speed things up a little bit. It should say in the exception where the error occured. Place the error as well like Boris said.

Comment: Added all the information I can about errors / exceptions above.

Comment: And you're sure nothing's using port 6789?

Comment: That's not a NullPointerException. That's a java.net.BindException, with a clear error message: Address already in use. You can't start two servers at once listening on the same port.

Comment: Ok. So something must have been listening on 6789.  I changed the port and the error is gone in eclipse.  But still, when I compile and run the code in my virtual machine, I get a "java.lang.NullPointerException" each time I attempt to access that port from my browser....    Image link to error i get: http://i.imgur.com/Z9Xzm5C.png

Comment: Is this a school assignment? Because if not, Just Don't Do That.

Answer (score 0):

`new BufferedReader(null)` will always `throw NullPointerException`. What did you except?

By the way, this is always a bad idea:

```
try {
    processRequest();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

If you don't know what to do with the exception, at least re-throw it to retain the stack trace:

```
try {
    processRequest();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This would have lead you to the line throwing the exception.

Comment: So how would you recommend initializing the BufferedReader in this case?  I have tried multiple ways and cant get around errors....

Comment: @ar13 You generally chain streams. `BufferedReader` expects a `Reader`. You could use `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))`. This is really simplified though because this second question cannot be answered in detail here. You may post a new question stating what you have tried so far and which errors you got.